# Sending Java int to C over TCP

Tags: java, c, tcp

I'm trying to send Java's signed integers over TCP to a C client.

At the Java side, I write the integers to the outputstream like so:

```
static ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4); // big-endian by default

public static void putInt(OutputStream out, int nr) throws IOException {
    wrapped.rewind();
    wrapped.putInt(nr);
    wrapped.rewind();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        out.write(wrapped.get());
}
```

At the C side, I read the integers like so:

```
int cnt = 0;
char buf[1];
char sizebuf[4];
while(cnt < 4) {
      iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, buf, 1, 0);
      if (iResult <= 0) continue;

      sizebuf[cnt] = buf[0];
      cnt++;
}
```

However, how do I convert the char array to an integer in C?

**Edit**

I have tried the following (and the reverse):

```
int charsToInt(char* array) {
     return (array[3] << 24) | (array[2] << 16) | (array[1] << 8) | array[0];   
}
```

Edited again, because I forgot the tags.

**Data**

For example of what happens currently:

I receive:

```
char 0
char 0
char 12
char -64
the int becomes 2448
```

and use the function for creating the int from the char array:

```
int charsToInt(char* array) {
    return ntohl(*((int*) array)); 
}
```

I expect the signed integer: 3264

**Update**
I will investigate more after some sleep..

**Update**
I have a Java client which interprets the integers correctly and receives the exact same bytes:

```
0
0
12
-64
```

Comment: @AndyThomas: Yes but he is looping

Comment: You say "I have tried the following", but you don't say how you know it didn't work.  What were the values in the array you provided, and what was the integer that was returned?  Did you verify this in a debugger or print the value?  If you printed it, what is the statement you used to print it?  That information is important.  Here's an example of it working:  http://ideone.com/EZNCGs

Comment: @RobotRock: can you at least print individual bytes

Comment: I am working on including the loose chars and the expected output, I will inclde them asap.

Comment: You're getting sign-extension problems. See my updated answer.

Comment: @user300234: That is indeed what I should do, I'm getting some problems with setting up my Java IDE and project though.

Comment: I have compared the individual bytes and they are exactly the same. The problem should really be in the way the integer is built. I will try using usigned chars next (although I have already tried Carl Norum's alternative solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on endianness, but you want either:

```
 int x = sizebuf[0] + 
         (sizebuf[1] << 8) +
         (sizebuf[2] << 16) +
         (sizebuf[3] << 24);
```

or:

```
 int x = sizebuf[3] + 
         (sizebuf[2] << 8) +
         (sizebuf[1] << 16) +
         (sizebuf[0] << 24);
```

Note that `sizebuf` needs to have an unsigned type for this to work correctly. Otherwise you need to mask off any sign-extended values you don't want:

```
 int x = (sizebuf[3] & 0x000000ff) + 
         ((sizebuf[2] << 8) & 0x0000ff00) +
         ((sizebuf[1] << 16) & 0x00ff0000) +
         ((sizebuf[0] << 24) & 0xff000000);
```

Comment: @RobotRock: Can you print individual bytes? What do you get on the C side?

Comment: @user300234, no casts are required. The default integer promotions will take care of it.

Comment: Your updated answer gives the same result as fge's answer; 2448.

Comment: Then your input data is wrong. Have you checked it?

Comment: @Carl Norum: I've just checked, and it might be that 2448 is actually correct. 2448 is what I would expect for the next integer, and that's probably not coincidental.

Comment: @user300234, read about [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

Answer (score 1):

The classical C library has the method you want already, and it is independent from the machine endianness: `ntohl`!

```
// buf is a char */uint8_t *
uint32_t from_network = *((uint32_t *) buf);
uint32_t ret = ntohl(from_network);
```

This, and `htonl` for the reverse etc expect that the "network order" is big endian.

(the code above presupposes that `buf` has at least 4 bytes; the return type, and argument type, of `ntohl` and `htonl` are `uint32_t`; the JLS defines an `int` as 4 bytes so you are guaranteed the result)

Comment: Watch out for alignment issues.

Comment: @CarlNorum hmwell, this code supposes that `buf` is a `char *`, yes; this is good enough, right?

Comment: No, that's not enough. If `buf` isn't 32-bit aligned, this code would crash on an ARM7, for example.

Answer (score 0):

To convert you char array, one possibility is to cast it to int* and to store the result :

```
int result = *((int*) sizebuf)
```

This is valid and one line. Other possibility is to compute integer from chars.

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 4; i++) 
     result = result << sizeof(char) + buf[0]
```

Choose the one that you prefer.

Alexis.

Edit :
sizeof(char) is 1 because sizeof return a Byte result. So the right line is :
result = result << (sizeof(char) * 8) + buf[0]

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`. Watch out for alignment issues with your first example, too.

Comment: Because I didn't know it, but it seems to be a good idea. Nevertheless, I'm not sure that it is so 'classical' as it is in strange headers. What happens with portability?

Comment: @CarlNorum Thanks to point out the sizeof mistake. I'm quite aware of alignment problem but I never encountered this error from time I code.